# Result of a select case statement for multiplication in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me how to use the result of a select case statement for multiplication?

```
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN unit = 'Sqft' THEN squareft
    WHEN unit = 'Lin.Inch' THEN value
 END) AS AREA, 
('AREA'* pieces) AS 'Total Area'
```

When I used my above query I get an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot multiple a string constant called `'AREA'` times anything.  You need to have a numeric value.

Comment: how do I provide  that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference an alias in the same statement where it is created.  You'll have to paste your subquery in place of 'AREA' or do what I would do and create a CTE for that calculation and reference the CTE in your main select.

Comment: Thanks.When I paste the subquery it works, but I was looking for something that is short. What is CTE?

Comment: CTE is Common Table Expression.  Have you ever seen `WITH` at the start of a query? PS - Mark this as the answer so future visitors know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT CASE 
   WHEN unit = 'Sqft' THEN squareft
   WHEN unit = 'Lin.Inch' THEN value
 END) AS AREA, 
('AREA'* pieces) AS 'Total Area'
```

'Area' like this is a string, and not a reference to the column area (error is the word 'area' cannot be multiplied by a number).  Use your case statement in the multiplication

```
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN unit = 'Sqft' THEN squareft
    WHEN unit = 'Lin.Inch' THEN value
 END) AS AREA, 
(CASE 
   WHEN unit = 'Sqft' THEN squareft
   WHEN unit = 'Lin.Inch' THEN value
 END* pieces) AS 'Total Area'
```

Comment: I tried the same and I get the results but I was looking for something small and convenient. Thanks

Comment: copy and pasting from the line above is about as convenient as you can get ;)   There isn't a smooth way of referring to a calculated column (or a case statement to determine a column) without repeating the case statement.  In the select line anyway.  You could use a CTE, but honestly...I think that's bulkier.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried to mark both your answers right but it doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: can only ever mark one...@jbarker2160 could use the magical overflow points more than I, mark his